# CircularFLO outputs .epub3 of wrong sizes

Tags: html, ios, ipad, viewport, epub3

I do convertion with [Circular FlO](http://www.circularsoftware.com/how-it-works/) from .indd to .epub.

The e-books I receive displayed fine in iBooks, but in my app pages are displayed zoomed. See the image and .epub in [dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/ov0r01koxf8nd59/u4j7fsBVbD/CircularFLO)

The problem is that CircularFLO creates .xhtmls in .epub with dimentions quite bigger than 1024*660 - size of our app screen on iPad4. My .indd file has page sizes 1024*660px but when I output it with CircularFLO .xhtml pages are 1749*1128px. See a line from .xhtml:
 
Why CircularFLO alters view port sizes and how to fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I work for Circular Software and can tell you why.
We are aiming our CircularFLO tool at publishers with existing print documents of any size and we don't assume any prior knowledge of viewports / pixel dimensions etc.

Instead we us the page proportion and adapt to 2 megapixels area (this area can be altered in the boilerplate, see our instructions page)

I will suggest we make an adaption to a forthcoming update whereby if pages have been designed using pixels rulers (instead of inches or mm for example) we offer to keep to the pixel dimensions exactly as the user has set.

Comment: - Thank you for promissing an update with aiming to pixel dimentions.
My second problem is that Live text doesn't pick up styles. I have live text in my document but it always TimesNewRoman. What I missed out?

Comment: Hi again. Please contact us directly at help at circular software dot com. I only chanced upon this a week after it was written... The probable reason is that you are not using a TrueType or Postscript font? but I'd need more info or to see your document to be sure.

Comment: I sent 2 letters using this http://www.circularsoftware.com/contact/
and 2 other here help@circularsoftware.com I didn't receive any response.
- I've solved my problem.
I've found one malfunction of CircularFLO: When you have in InDesign  two text columns and then place there a picture, so that it supersedes text and text goes beneath the picture, and then in .epub the text will appear over the picture, overlapping it, and without style. See what it looks like https://www.dropbox.com/lightbox/home/Public/CircularFLO
Could you, please, fix this in future updates of CircularFLO?